# Post PHP script hidden with img

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with images, on the images is a button to favourite the image.
If they click the button I have a PHP script which adds the image to their favorites.

I want to execute the PHP code without going to the page with the PHP script.

my html is like this:

```
 <div id="image">
    <form action="favoriet.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="aid" value="<?php echo $subimgid?>">
            <input type="image" src="/media/img/icons/twitter.png" alt="Submit button">
            </form>
                </div>
```

so I post the subimgid to favoriet.php and in favoriet.php I run the script which inserts it in the database using the posted value aid an the session user id.
Everything is working but I don't want the page favoriet.php to open in a screen.

I think jQuery/ajax is needed, not sure.

Comment: Yes, you are correct..you need ajax to save the record silently...

Comment: Ajax indeed, you wont be able to do it without Ajax xD

Comment: I think there are enough tutorials out there in the web how to do this using Ajax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would do is add a class to the img `favimg` and then add another attribute called `data-id` which holds the id. Then you can use jQuery directly on the image and dont need the form.

Below code will submit a POST request to `favoriet.php` with the ID that is stored in the `data-id` attibute

```
<img class='favimg' data-id="<?php echo $subimgid?>" src="/media/img/icons/twitter.png" alt="Submit button">

<script>
$('.favimg').click(function() {
  $.post('favoriet.php', { aid: $(this).attr('data-id')});
});
</script>
```

On a side note: The alt text should say something about the image. So if the image is the twitter logo, I would use 'twitter' as the alt text. That would create a better index for search engines.

An alt of `submit button` is usefull if there is only one image on the page and its goal is to submit a complete form. What you want to submit is "I clicked on the twitter button" so I user must know that it contains twitter logo.

Comment: I would recommend keeping the form, hooking on to the .submit() event and returning false on a successful submit. This way the site will degrade gracefully in the (ok admittedly unlikely) event that the user has Javascript disabled.

Comment: Good call brad. That would be best. But then your `favoriet.php` must also know the difference between a AJAX call and a regular submit because with ajax he might return a `JSON true` and normal request is return to page. But I thought that was beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an answer that avoids the need for Posting or AJAX, to show that this can be done without either.

#### image tag communication

You could use the image tag to communicate to the server:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="image/to/be/favourited.jpg" data-aid="123" />
  <a href="favoriet-fallback.php?aid=123">
    <img src="/media/img/icons/twitter.png" />
  </a>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.image > a').click(function(){
      var
        img = $(this).siblings('img'),
        src = img.attr('src'),
        aid = img.attr('data-aid'),
        esc = window.encodeURIComponent ? encodeURIComponent : escape
      ;
      /// here you have the choice of using the image to be favourited or
      /// the twitter icon. I chose the favourited image for this example.
      img.attr('src', 'favoriet.php?src=' + esc(src) + '&aid=' + esc(aid) );
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

With this code you would need to modify `favoriet.php` so that it would serve back the image specified in `src` using a simple `readfile` method, and it would be good to create a `favoriet-fallback.php` although it isn't 100% necessary.

#### script/image tag injection

You could also inject a new script or image tag to perform your request.

```
<script>
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.image > a').click(function(){
      var
        img = $(this).siblings('img'),
        src = img.attr('src'),
        aid = img.attr('data-aid'),
        esc = window.encodeURIComponent ? encodeURIComponent : escape
      ;
      /// you could build a script tag or a pixel image here
      var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = 'favoriet.php?src=' + esc(src) + '&aid=' + esc(aid);
      jQuery('body').append(script);
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

This example would obviously mean that `favoriet.php` should return fully-fledged JavaScript which could interact with the existing page.

The above are just a few foolish examples that use a GET request in-place of a POST — which does have it's benefits and also it's own downsides. Neither of these examples require jQuery, I've just used it for speed and clarity.

Hugo's design is far more elegant, but I only mention these just to prove that AJAX is not the only way.

Comment: Having PHP return images is always slower then direct access. So having favoriet.php return the image is not realy a good option. I would only recommend using things like this if cross site scripting is causing problems. What is your motivation to not use ajax?

Comment: @HugoDelsing I'm not motivated against AJAX at all (was using it way before it was even known as that), and as I stated at the end of my post your answer is best (hence my +1). I just don't like seeing comments where it is stated this is only achievable with AJAX... There is always more than one way in web development. Yes true, images parsed by PHP will be slower -- if I was to really consider the first answer I'd probably operate it on the twitter icon instead, which wouldn't suffer as much from a delay.. (but then I probably wouldn't use it as a solution).

Comment: Ah I missed the comment that you need AJAX. Thats definitly not true. But I guess a lot of people also think you need jQuery to do anything these days. Never heared of javascript :)

Comment: @HugoDelsing No worries -- comments are far too easy to miss on SO. Heh, yep I still find it baffling when an OP treats jQuery as if it's a language in itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, Ajax is required. Jquery is the framework of javascript.

So back to your question.

Here is what you need to do. Bind a function to onclick="" of the image button(whatever you have used) and pass the id of the image as parameter.

```
onclick="add_fav('2')"
```

When the user clicks on it your add_fav function will fun and the id of the image will be sent as parameter. Inside the function post this value to your favorite.php.

```
function add_fav(id){
    var data={'image_id':id}
    var url="favorite.php";

    $.ajax({type:"POST",url,data,function(response){ // handle the response
    }});

}
```

You can retrieve the value in favoriete.php using

```
$id=$_POST['image_id'];
```

Then save it in database and echo back a success message.